# Rails Globalize plugin help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, internationalization, globalization

Has anyone gotten the Globalize plugin to work Rails 2.3.2 or later? If so, could you direct me to some useful info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is. The last release of Globalize was for Rails 1.2.

However there's the [globalize 2](http://github.com/joshmh/globalize2/) plugin which is for rails > 2.0 and will probably work with 2.3.2.
You'll find info to it in the README file and in their [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/joshmh/globalize2)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware there is globalize 2 now, but I haven't found any good instructions/documentation. Even http://globalize-rails.org/ is extremely outdated.